# Does anyone know where I can find a complete code example of Paypal Transparent Redirect in C# or VB.NET?

Tags: asp.net, api, paypal

I only found one example of their transparent redirect and it was in PHP. It also did not load a previously authorized customer's billing/cc info.

My intention is to load the customer's info into a form, let them revise it and save.

I also need to create or update a recurring payment for them.

Unfortunately transparent redirect examples are hard to find, and worse .NET is very hard to find.

Comment: Can you reference the PHP example?  Should be possible to convert the same logic to .NET.

Comment: What do you mean by a "transparent redirect" in this context?

Comment: https://www.x.com/developers/community/blogs/pp_integrations_nate/payflow-transparent-redirect

I request a customers billing info from paypal and display it in a form, pre-filled. The customer may then update his info and credit card number. Upon submit the form is posted to paypal directly. Paypal then redirects from their server back to my page with some additional data that I can display on the page, including success or error codes. The process gives me the freedom to design the page markup entirely and maintain pci compliance. This is how I've done it with Braintree.